# Using a loop to process and format multiple .csv files

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, lapply

I have a bunch of csv files that I am reading into R.

Here's sample data to help with this inquiry.

```
ABC_H <- structure(list(Name = c("Jim Smith", "John Doe"), user_id = c(23L, 25L), sales = c(300L, 140L), shape = c(6L, 200L), size = c(402L, 305L)),row.names= c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), user_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), sales = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), shape = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), size = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
BCD_H <- structure(list(Name = c("Jim Smith", "John Doe"), user_id = c(23L, 25L), sales = c(190L, 120L), shape = c(10L, 5L), size = c(500L, 200L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec =structure(list(cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), user_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), sales = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), shape = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), size = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
XYZ_H <- structure(list(Name = c("Jim Smith", "John Doe"), user_id = c(23L, 25L), sales = c(190L, 120L), shape = c(10L, 5L), size = c(500L, 200L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec =structure(list(cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), user_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), sales = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), shape = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), size = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))

ABC_P <- structure(list(Name = c("Alex Smith", "John Curry"), user_id = c(102L, 433L), color = c(164L, 153L), number = c(20L, 3L), scale = c(6L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), user_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), color = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), number = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), scale = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
BCD_P <- structure(list(Name = c("Alex Smith", "John Curry"), user_id = c(102L, 433L), color = c(300L, 200L), number = c(100L, 4L), scale = c(2L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), user_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), color = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), number = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), scale = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
XYZ_P <- structure(list(Name = c("Alex Smith", "John Curry"), user_id = c(102L, 433L), color = c(300L, 200L), number = c(100L, 4L), scale = c(2L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), user_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), color = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), number = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), scale = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
```

The naming convention I am using is based on the file name.

Here's an example of the manual code I'm currently using to load the .csv files.  There are several other csv files.  The working directory is loaded at the top of the script.

```
ABC_H <- read_csv(file.path(getwd(), "input_data","ABC_H_2018.csv"))
ABC_P <- read_csv(file.path(getwd(), "input_data","ABC_P_2018.csv"))
BCD_H <- read_csv(file.path(getwd(), "input_data","BCD_H_2018.csv"))
BCD_P <- read_csv(file.path(getwd(), "input_data","BCD_P_2018.csv"))
XYZ_H <- read_csv(file.path(getwd(), "input_data","XYZ_H_2018.csv"))
XYZ_P <- read_csv(file.path(getwd(), "input_data","XYZ_P_2018.csv"))
```

I am then using dplyr to format each file individually.  All files that contain the suffix "H" will get formatted using the same columns, and all files that contain "P" will get formatted using the same columns.  Here's a sample of the dplyr code I have for the first 2 with the suffix "H".

```
ABC_H_formatted <- ABC_H %>%
mutate(data_source = "ABC")%>%
rename(user_id = user)%>%
select(user_id, Name, data_source, size, shape, sales)

BCD_H_formatted <- BCD_H %>%
mutate(data_source = "BCD")%>%
rename(user_id = user)%>%
select(user_id, Name, data_source, size, shape, sales)


XYZ_H_formatted <- BCD_H %>%
mutate(data_source = "BCD")%>%
rename(user_id = user)%>%
select(user_id, Name, data_source, size, shape, sales)

ABC_P_formatted <- ABC_P %>%
mutate(data_source = "ABC")%>%
rename(user_id = user)%>%
select(user_id, Name, data_source, color, number, scale)

BCD_P_formatted <- BCD_P %>%
mutate(data_source = "BCD")%>%
rename(user_id = user)%>%
select(user_id, Name, data_source, color, number, scale)

XYZ_P_formatted <- XYZ_P %>%
mutate(data_source = "XYZ")%>%
rename(user_id = user)%>%
select(user_id, Name, data_source, color, number, scale)
```

Here's what I'd like to do.

1. Create 2 loops, one for all files with the _H suffix, and one for all files with the _P suffix
2. Create a data_source column based on the file name (as above)
3. Select the columns listed above for each file
4. Create a data.frame for all of the _H, and one for the _P

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is where you really get into the idea of writing a custom function to do what you want and then applying that function to a list of objects.  This is the manner that iteration is typically approached in R.

Since you're already using `dplyr`, I'm going to show a `tidyverse` approach (yet this can easily be done in base R as well).  Create a function that does the processing steps you want, and also assigns a suffix and data_source column (extracted from the filename with some regular expressions and `stringr`).

Then you'll want to get a list of files from your directory, using a matching pattern to get all files rather than manually entering each one.

Finally, we use `map_df` from `purrr` to "map" the `read_data` function to each file in the list and then bind all results together into a data frame.  This doesn't produce the two data frames that you wish but with the `suffix` column, you can easily subset out each piece.

You may run into some errors since I don't have your data to test this on.  In the future, it's better to make a reproducible example of your problem so we can help you better!

```
library(tidyverse) #dplyr, purrr, stringr, readr

read_data <- function(file) {

  name <- basename(file)

  suffix <- str_extract(name, "(?<=_)[HP]")

  data_source <- str_extact(name, "[A-Z]+(?=_)")

  if (suffix == "P") {
    cols <- c("suffix", "user_id", "Name", "data_source", "color", "number", "scale")
  } 

  if (suffix == "H") {
    cols <- c("suffix", "user_id", "Name", "data_source", "size", "shape", "sales")
  }

  read_csv(file) %>% 
    rename(user_id = user) %>% 
    mutate(datar_source = data_source,
           suffix = suffix) %>% 
    select(one_of(cols))

}
files <- dir(file.path(getwd(), "input_data"), pattern = "ABC|BCD", full.names = TRUE)

result <- map_df(files, read_data)
```

Comment: Thanks Jake.  I added a reproducible example to hopefully help give me more specific guidance on this issue.  In this case, I added a 3rd dataset(XYZ).  Both the _H, and _P files have 6 files each.  Is there a way to change the above function based on the example above, and knowing that there are several datasets for each?

Comment: Yes, you can use the example above and construct the logic you need.  It would be an if-else block around the `suffix` that would pass the columns you want to `select`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively new to r and don't understand how to construct the if/else block for the 12 different csv files (6 each for _H, and _P).  Would it be possible to give a little more guidance?  Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer.  This will give you one big data frame of both combined, with `NA` values in column names that aren't selected via prefixes.  You can work on it from there to subset and pluck out into two data fames accordingly

Comment: Thanks Jake.  I used my sample data and the result frame is giving me 0 results.  It appears that the    files object is empty.

Comment: Does there need to be an else statement after the if?  I'm getting an error of Error in if (suffix == "P") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed